# How to define the return type for `Promise.all`?

Tags: typescript, es6-promise

Not sure what is going on here. Did I do something weird with my types...

```
const reflect = (promise): Promise<Reflection> =>
    promise.then(
        (value) => ({ value, resolved: true }),
        (error) => ({ error, rejected: true })
    );

const to = (promiseArr) => {
    return Promise.all(promiseArr.map(reflect)).then((sources: Reflection[]) => sources);
};
```

```
Argument of type '(sources: Reflection[]) => Reflection[]' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: [unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown]) => Reflection[] | PromiseLike<Reflection[]>'.
  Types of parameters 'sources' and 'value' are incompatible.
    Type '[unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown]' is not assignable to type 'Reflection[]'.
      Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'Reflection'.ts(2345)
```

Comment: how is this a javascript question though ?

Comment: @Noob thanks for the scrutinizing and discerning eye. I removed the label.

Comment: I'd recommend checking out [Promise.allSettled](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled), which might be a more idiomatic solution to error handling:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what your `Reflection` type is, but it sounds like it should probably take a type parameter of the resolve value, if the Promise resolves, probably something like

```
type Reflection<T> = {
    value: T;
    resolved: true;
} | {
    error: unknown;
    rejected: true;
}
```

Then, in `reflect` and `to`, make sure to denote the types of the arguments, and pass those types as the type parameters:

```
const reflect = <T>(promise: Promise<T>): Promise<Reflection<T>> =>
    promise.then(
        value => ({ value, resolved: true }),
        error => ({ error, rejected: true })
    );

const to = <T>(promiseArr: Array<Promise<T>>) => {
    return Promise.all(promiseArr.map(reflect)).then((sources: Array<Reflection<T>>) => sources);
};
```

This compiles properly, and TS detects `to`'s type as:

```
const to: <T>(promiseArr: Promise<T>[]) => Promise<Reflection<T>[]>
```

Though, note that the last `.then` in `to` isn't doing anything, so you can simplify it to

```
const to = <T>(promiseArr: Array<Promise<T>>) => {
    return Promise.all(promiseArr.map(reflect))
};
```

[Working demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=19&pc=7#code/C4TwDgpgBAShBmAbCBjYBLA9gOwDwBUA+KAXigG8AoKGqANwENEBXCALinwG5raAnCAGdMiOhAAmHYH1Y8AvlAA+FXjQh8+mPh2bYA1tkwB3bD1pQBAK1TAJUmRHk8UOQcAsJkaUlAKEAFGCaALboguxQAAohYRB+AJQc0Zih4bhwSDZYeETEJISqUEEpsQB0wAAWENj+heaMLND5UP7k9EysADQewqJ2UNKsUHLxnXW06pp8pMStUJNa3VY2-YPQI2Pm8TyULthuA5g+foEx4QCCGhyXfAwguMmpcbnxMyrmAsDMfNhRZxClJiIU4lC4aUrBBhgfwCTJoeLbShyZyudwCQTMRDAQQ+YCYfwAbUeZXRIjE-gATPEALqIgD0dIGgkQ6GwwDY4jCDAARsgALTYCAAD2AfJZgo4hj5SEwDAw2AA5nzik9BJR0ZjseUqjV-AwNK9mlRzPAtC09gd0LZglBMPAoPq+K9jeZaOh7f4AOSkvriT1QVkB63O8auqAW9zYZg2shWiDBUoNWSh10MqBRm1hIqaSB8RAgAbgCQOnEZ7nqFNyQpVkZcIA)

Comment: Having a hard time understanding what `const reflect = <T>(promise: Promise<T>): Promise<Reflection<T>> =>` is supposed to be.

Comment: The `<T>` is a type parameter. It means that when the argument is `(promise: Promise<T>)` - a Promise that resolves to something of type T - then the function returns a `Reflection` which, if resolved, resolves to that same type T; this is the sort of static type checking you want to be able to perform at compile-time.

Comment: Got it. I think there is a syntax error then because my ts linter is not getting it.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong. I added a link to the TS playground, it doesn't see any errors

Comment: nvm i found the error. I was getting some silly behavior cause I was in react land. Moved my utils to a ts file works like a charm. Bless you.

Comment: Question: Why isn't the `then` needed in the `to`? don't we still need to resolve the `Promise.all`? We loop through the array of promises with the map, and resolve those with reflect, does the `Promise.all` somehow know all those are resolved?

Comment: `to` is already returning a Promise which resolves to an array of Reflections. The Promises get turned into their resolve values through the `Promise.all` (and then the `reflect` reformats it). In *every case* where you see `.then(arg => arg)`, it's superfluous - it takes in a Promise which resolves to `arg`, and results in a Promise which resolves to `arg`. It doesn't do anything.